# Print all table data from mysql into a html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been trying to print all users into a html table. The objective is that the site administrator can edit the information.
I've done the following code so far, but I can't understand how I will print User1_Name, User1_Email and password into a table row. I want this for every user on the database.

```
<body>
    <div class="edituser"> 
      <h1> Edit Users </h1>

      <table>
          <tr>
              <th>User Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Password</th>

          </tr>
   <?php include("include/headerhomeadmin.php");?>


        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        /*$line[]=$row;*/  

        echo 

        $userusername =$row['username'];
        $useremail =$row['email'];
        $userpassword=$row['password'];

        ?>
      <td><?php echo implode(" ", $line)?></td> 

        <?php } ?>

        </table>       

    </div>
```

Can someone help me?

UPDATE:
My code is now printing the first username, the email from the second user and the password from de third user.
The code is the following:

```
<body>
<div class="edituser"> 
  <h1> Editar Utilizadores </h1>

  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Nome de Utilizador</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Password</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
```

```
    <?php while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

            $userusername =$row['username'];
    ?>

          <td> <?php echo $userusername ?>  </td>

      <?php while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

            $useremail =$row['email'];

    ?>

          <td> <?php echo $useremail ?>  </td>

      <?php while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

            $userpassword=$row['password'];

    ?>
          <td> <?php echo $userpassword ?>  </td>


    <?php }
    }
```

}?>

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) You're imploding `$line`, not `$row`. 2) You can use the loop to echo out the table rows with the values inside the cells.

Comment: You could also just echo the `<td>` and `</td>` tags before and after echoing each element you want in the table and avoid imploding. Would be cleaner to read. Also, don't forget to start off each loop with a `<tr>` and finishing each loop with a `</tr>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {?>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Password</th>

  </tr>
 <?php while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 

   <tr> 
          <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>

   </tr>

 <?php }?>
 </table>
 <?php
 }

 else{
 echo "0 results";
 }
 ?>
```